# How to start Scanner using the Flashlight with ZXing?

Tags: java, android, zxing, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I want to make a QR Code scanner using ZXing library.
In my `build.gradle`, I have added the following code:

```groovy
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
}
```

and when I click on a `Button`, it executes the following code:

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MainActivity.this);
```

and the QR-Scanner scanner works.

Now, I want start the `Scanner` with the flash light. How can I do this?
I've searching around the web, but examples confused me.

So, how can I start the `Scanner` using the flash light?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Source Code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUN3RyeGtuUGpHQnc

[image]

**Add Dependency in Manifest File - It's Working**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            String cameraId = null; // Usually back camera is at 0 position.
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);  

 // TODO  Turn ON  Flash Light On
                mScannerView.setFlash(true);    
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: this doesn't work, produces error 'Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user'

Answer (score 0):

```
            Camera camera  =Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters p;
            p = camera.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(p);

            CameraConfigurationUtils.setTorch(p,true);
```

Using this you can on the torch for barcode/qrcode scanner in android studio.